# WPF: ListView из TextBox для ObservableCollection<string>

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть `ListView`. Он привязан к коллекции строк. Надо описать его `ItemTemplate` так, чтобы он представлял собой поле ввода для каждой строки в коллекции.

Если написать

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>    
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

то выдает ошибку `InvalidOperationException: Для двусторонней сборки требуется Path или XPath.`.

Как я понимаю, для двусторонней привязки нужно указать `{binding <тут поле>}`. Но у обычного `string` просто нет никаких полей.

Comment: А это не должно быть string, а должно быть набором string в контейнере ObservableCollection. Тогда конструкция `{Binding}` будет рабочей. А `ItemsSource` у элемента должен указывать на ObservableCollection.

Comment: Двустороннюю привязку можно использовать только со свойствами, у которых есть и get, и set. string в ObservableCollection - это вообще не свойства, но к ним можно одностороннюю привязку делать {Binding Mode=OneWay}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы код заработал необходимо переписать так:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>    
    <DataTemplate>
         <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Дело в том что по умолчанию режим привязки TwoWay.А к коллекции строк, а не объектов возможна только односторонняя привязка.

Полноценно рабочим вариантом будет создание коллекции объектов класса, у которого будет **string {get;set;}** метод, к которому и надо биндить **item**

Comment: Точно, Спасибо)